# Probability that the tallest and shortest person are sitting next to each other if they cannot sit at either end?

Tags: combinatorics

> Eight people of different heights are to be seated in a row. The
>   shortest and tallest in this group are not seated at either end. What
>   is the probability that:
>
> (a) The tallest and shortest persons are sitting next to each other?
>
> (b) There is one person sitting between the tallest and shortest?

My approach to (a) goes like that: the probability should be equal to $$P=\frac{6*5*5!*2!}{8!-7!-7!+2!6!}$$ The reason for the denominator is because I subtract from the total number of combinations those combinations where the tallest is at one end (he/she is "fixed", the rest can arrange in $7!$ ways, the same goes for the shortest, finally I add $2!6!$ to avoid double counting. The reason for the numerator is because if the tallest and shortest can't be at the ends, then, since there is eight people in total, one end can be occupied in 6 ways and the other end in 5 ways. If the tallest and shortest are to be sitting together, then instead of $6!$, I multiply by $5!2!$. My textbook says the answer to (a) is $\frac{5}{28}$, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't there two ends? Seems like your reasoning would require $8!-2\cdot 7!-2\cdot 7!+2!6!$. You get the same answer I did if you use this formula

Comment: You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick two seats for the tallest and shortest (out of the six that are not end seats,) then pick randomly which one sits in those two seats. Then pick $6!$ different ways to seat the rest of the people.

This gives $\binom{6}{2}\cdot 2!\cdot 6!$ different possibilities.

Then there are only $5$ different ways to choose the two seats in the first step so that they are together, so there are $5\cdot 2!\cdot 6!$ different ways for them to be seated together.

So for (a) we should get:

$$\frac{5}{\binom{6}{2}}=\frac{1}{3}$$

For (b), you do similarly: How many ways are there to choose the two seats so that they have a single seat between them?

There are actually $2\cdot 7!$ ways for the tallest person to be at either end: $7!$ for each end. So your formula should be:

$$P=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot 5!\cdot2!}{8!-2\cdot 7!-2\cdot 7!+2!6!}$$

Which also gives $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: That's funny, because it's my second textbook at that level and in both books the chapter about combinatorics is riddled with mistakes. :)